# Why does SQL-Server save duplicate data for a single entry?

Tags: php, sql-server, database, forms, crud

I've developed a CRUD based web application in php. It's a form whose input data gets saved in a sql server database.

Even when the user fills it once, the database is saving multiple entries for it.

The problem is in the database it seems as the form gets submitted successfully.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Here's the code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once 'db-connect.php';
require_once 'email.php';        

if(isset($_POST['pEmail'])){
    $fName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fName") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fName') : null;
    $lName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "lName")? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lName') : null;
    $mName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "mName")? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mName') : null;
    $tempRace = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "race", FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
    $race = (is_array($tempRace)) ? implode(',', $tempRace) : null;
    $hEthnicity = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "hEthnicity") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hEthnicity') : null;
    $gender = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "gender") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gender') : null;
    $age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "age") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age') : null;
    $education = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "education") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'education') : null;
    $gpa = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "gpa") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gpa') : null;
    $hPhone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "hPhone") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hPhone') : null;
    $cPhone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cPhone") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cPhone') : null;
    $pEmail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "pEmail") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pEmail') : null;
    $aEmail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "aEmail") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'aEmail') : null;
    $inputAddress = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "inputAddress") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'inputAddress') : null;
    $inputCity = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "inputCity") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'inputCity') : null;

    $conn = DB::databaseConnection();
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.premedical ( FName,LName, MidInitial, Race, Ethnicity, Gender, Age, SchoolYear, Gpa, HPhone, CPhone, PEmail, AEmail, MailAddress, MailCity) VALUES 
            ( :fName,:lName, :mName, :race, :hEthnicity, :gender,:age, :education, :gpa, :hPhone, :cPhone, :pEmail, :aEmail, :inputAddress, :inputCity)";

    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($fName,  $lName, $mName, $race, $hEthnicity, $gender, $age,   $education, $gpa, $hPhone, $cPhone, $pEmail, $aEmail, $inputAddress, $inputCity));

    if ($q->execute()) {
        $conn->commit(); 

        if (Form::mailer($fName,  $lName, $mName, $race, $hEthnicity, $gender, $age,   $education, $gpa, $hPhone, $cPhone, $pEmail, $aEmail, $inputAddress, $inputCity)) {
            echo '
            <script >
                alert("Thank you for registration.");
            </script>';
        }

        return true; 
    } else {
        echo '
        <script>
            alert("Error, please try submitting again. Error code 1");
            window.history.back();
        </script>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't, your php is very likely running the command twice; SQL Server is simply doing what it's told. Without your PHP or SQL Code, however, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Oh. Why is php running it twice? Any possible answer to that?

Comment: As @Larnu said...."Without your PHP or SQL Code, however, this is impossible to answer."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: *"Any possible answer to that?"* Uses of my Crystal ball are charged at £10,000 per use, and are non-refundable even if the guess is incorrect. If, however, I don't need to use my Crystal ball, I'll be happy to not charge the fee for it's use. To do so, however, the volunteers here *will* need that PHP and SQL code.

Comment: Let me update the question with the code.

Comment: @AAM post the *relevant* code, don't just dump all of your code

Comment: Added the code. Please check

Comment: @AAM post the *relevant* code, don't just dump all of your code

Comment: I've just added the form and the sql

Comment: Should I filter it more?

Comment: *Remove* the form, it's irrelevant. If you remove *most* of the PHP code before execution you'll see you're calling `execute` twice. `$q->execute(array(...));
if ($q->execute()) `

Comment: Will that execute it twice? Isn't it just a condition?

Comment: You can store the response of the first execute in a variable and use that variable in your if-statement: `$response = $q->execute(...); if ($response) { ... }`. Then you will check the same response instead of executing the statement again. You also don't need `beginTransaction()` and `commit()` if you're just making one single insert query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `$q->execute` fires off the execute procedure, even if you're using it in a logic check - so it's executing twice. You should update it to something like:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once 'db-connect.php';
require_once 'email.php';        

if(isset($_POST['pEmail'])){
    $fName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fName") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fName') : null;
    $lName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "lName")? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lName') : null;
    $mName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "mName")? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mName') : null;
    $tempRace = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "race", FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
    $race = (is_array($tempRace)) ? implode(',', $tempRace) : null;
    $hEthnicity = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "hEthnicity") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hEthnicity') : null;
    $gender = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "gender") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gender') : null;
    $age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "age") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age') : null;
    $education = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "education") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'education') : null;
    $gpa = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "gpa") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gpa') : null;
    $hPhone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "hPhone") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hPhone') : null;
    $cPhone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cPhone") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cPhone') : null;
    $pEmail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "pEmail") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pEmail') : null;
    $aEmail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "aEmail") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'aEmail') : null;
    $inputAddress = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "inputAddress") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'inputAddress') : null;
    $inputCity = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "inputCity") ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'inputCity') : null;

    $conn = DB::databaseConnection();
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.premedical ( FName,LName, MidInitial, Race, Ethnicity, Gender, Age, SchoolYear, Gpa, HPhone, CPhone, PEmail, AEmail, MailAddress, MailCity) VALUES 
            ( :fName,:lName, :mName, :race, :hEthnicity, :gender,:age, :education, :gpa, :hPhone, :cPhone, :pEmail, :aEmail, :inputAddress, :inputCity)";

    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result = $q->execute(array($fName,  $lName, $mName, $race, $hEthnicity, $gender, $age,   $education, $gpa, $hPhone, $cPhone, $pEmail, $aEmail, $inputAddress, $inputCity));

    if ($result) {
        $conn->commit(); 

        if (Form::mailer($fName,  $lName, $mName, $race, $hEthnicity, $gender, $age,   $education, $gpa, $hPhone, $cPhone, $pEmail, $aEmail, $inputAddress, $inputCity)) {
            echo '
            <script >
                alert("Thank you for registration.");
            </script>';
        }

        return true; 
    } else {
        echo '
        <script>
            alert("Error, please try submitting again. Error code 1");
            window.history.back();
        </script>';
    }
}
?>
```